# How to ask to magento team about my extension status?

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, marketplace

I have submitted my extension on http://marketplace.magento.com for Magento 1.
It's been 31 days in technical review but still not any response from Magento team.
It's still in technical review. Is there any email where I can email them and ask for my extension?

Please suggest me, give me email id where I can contact them, what do I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can send an email about it with the email address `marketplace@magento.com` . Try to explain your question with details as much as you can. They will create an Internal ticket for you after sending an email. They will surely get back to you

**UPDATE [17/09/2018]**

Magento marketplace launch new support panel for ticket https://marketplacesupport.magento.com/hc/en-us  From here you can create a support ticket and you will also find more Info.

Comment: Thanks, I have sent an email.It has been generated ticket.